# Responsive images not flowing correctly

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

I have a layout and i'm trying to add in a row of images that will sit underneath the 'just arrived' section and no matter what i try the images keep flowing underneath each other.

Can anyone see what im doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: My code is at: https://jsfiddle.net/5cripted/9qyjhjto/2/. 

I'm trying to get a layout similar to: https://jsfiddle.net/5cripted/sz4k9pv5/, but i can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `<li>` elements are `display: block` by default. Give them `float: left` and you're all set.

```
.wrap {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I tried float left, but then the images dont go into big boxes when the screen is made smaller, like the other images on the page. Someone else suggested using some divs and i tried that, but the margins are all off: https://jsfiddle.net/5cripted/v2qfsnqz/. I cant seem to get the just arrived and the images below to line up properly.

Answer (score 0):

They are flowing underneath each other because each image is wrapped with a block element, in this case a `<div>`. Remove the div or set it's display value to `inline-block`.

The smaller images have each a display value of `list-item` which positions the items like a vertical list as well.

**inline-block**

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: left;  
}

.wrapper a {
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

**display block and floats**

```css
/* Clearfix */
.wrapper::after {
  content: ''
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.wrapper a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

img {
  /* Fixes whitespace below each image */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

**Flexbox**

Use this if you don't need to support old versions of Internet Explorer (<11).

```css
/* Clearfix */
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper a {
  width: 50%;
}

img {
  /* Stretch the image for demo purposes */
  width: 100%;
  /* Fixes whitespace below each image */
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I tried float left, but then the images dont go into big boxes when the screen is made smaller, like the other images on the page. Someone else suggested using some divs and i tried that, but the margins are all off: https://jsfiddle.net/5cripted/v2qfsnqz/. I cant seem to get the just arrived and the images below to line up properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small code for you. check this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
 }

div.imagecontainer
{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 
}

div.imagecontainer ul {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 padding:0;
}

div.imagecontainer ul li{
 list-style-type: none;
 width: 20%;
 height: 200px;
 float: left;
}

div.imagecontainer ul li img
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

</style>
<body>

<div class="imagecontainer">
 <ul>
  <li><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1006/9816/files/Home-LisaKay.jpg?13639724066688423445"></li>
  <li><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1006/9816/files/Home-LisaKay.jpg?13639724066688423445"></li>
  <li><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1006/9816/files/Home-Blaithin_f3f568d3-849a-4271-a640-b2517965adda.jpg?16480572688008041262"></li>
  <li><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1006/9816/files/Home-LisaKay.jpg?13639724066688423445"></li>
  <li><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1006/9816/files/Home-LisaKay.jpg?13639724066688423445"></li>
  
 </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).resize(function(){
  //alert("resizing");
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if(windowWidth < 600)
    {
     $("div.imagecontainer ul li").css({"width":"100%","height":"400px"});
    }
    else
    {
     $("div.imagecontainer ul li").css({"width":"20%","height":"200px"});
    }
    
 });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

but I used small jquery. you can change the conditions and I used all `css` ans `js` internally.

other thing is `width` and `heidht` and other things are depend on your need change those(number of images you decide to put in a line), as your need.

I think this may not 100% fit to your need.I recommend to use bootstrap. 
copy past and try this.hope this will help to you.

Comment: The images don't seem retain their aspect ratio. They appear squashed for me.